# Which attribute replace for "relativePercent" at Android-Studio 2.2

Tags: android, android-studio, android-constraintlayout

I used constraint layout Android Studio 2.2 with "constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha3" dependency before, but now i am using constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha7, "relativePercent" attribute is not exists. Which attribute replace for "relativePercent"?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `app:layout_constraintGuide_percent` in a guideline to set its position using percent.

```
<android.support.constraint.Guideline
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:id="@+id/guideline1"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    app:layout_constraintGuide_percent="0.70"/>
```

Then you can use the guideline, for example, as a layout constraint target of a component.

```
app:layout_constraintLeft_toLeftOf="@+id/guideline1"
```

Comment: Thank you, but **app:layout_constraintGuide_percent** is not working, i see that just **app:layout_constraintGuide_end** and **app:layout_constraintGuide_begin** is working??

Comment: Make sure you're using at least version alpha6 of the library `com.android.support.constraint:constraint-layout:1.0.0-alpha6`

Comment: i have just created a new layout. it works. But the layout which i created before is not. i will check it. Thank you

Comment: it works when i move Guidelines to above other views.